# How can I get both the process id and the exit code from a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I need a bash script that does the following:

- Starts a background process with all output directed to a file
- Writes the process's exit code to a file
- Returns the process's pid (right away, not when process exits).
- The script must exit

I can get the pid but not the exit code:

```
$ executable >>$log 2>&1 &
pid=`jobs -p`
```

Or, I can capture the exit code but not the pid:

```
$ executable >>$log;
# blocked on previous line until process exits
echo $0 >>$log;
```

How can I do all of these at the same time?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The pid is in `$!`, no need to run `jobs`.  And the return status is returned by `wait`:

```
$executable >> $log 2>&1 &
pid=$!
wait $!
echo $?  # return status of $executable
```

**EDIT 1**

If I understand the additional requirement as stated in a comment, and you want the script to return immediately (without waiting for the command to finish), then it will not be possible to have the initial script write the exit status of the command.  But it is easy enough to have an intermediary write the exit status as soon as the child finishes.  Something like:

```
sh -c "$executable"' & echo pid=$! > pidfile; wait $!; echo $? > exit-status' &
```

should work.

**EDIT 2**

As pointed out in the comments, that solution has a race condition: the main script terminates before the pidfile is written.  The OP solves this by doing a polling sleep loop, which is an abomination and I fear I will have trouble sleeping at night knowing that I may have motivated such a travesty.  IMO, the correct thing to do is to wait until the child is done.   Since that is unacceptable, here is a solution that blocks on a read until the pid file exists instead of doing the looping sleep:

```
{ sh -c "$executable > $log 2>&1 &"'
echo $! > pidfile
echo   # Alert parent that the pidfile has been written
wait $!
echo $? > exit-status
' & } | read
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is pretty close. I'm afraid I left out one other requirement. The bash script must finish. If I run "wait $pid; echo $? >>$log" in a backgrounded helper script, I will get a "not a child" error.

Comment: If you want the script to exit before the child finishes, it is not possible to write the exit code of the child without invoking a temporal anomaly of some sort.

Comment: Wrap the whole `sh -c "( $executable"' ...exit-status)' &` in the sub-shell parentheses.  That lets the subshell get on with its life while the parent gets on with whatever it needs to do.  You might want to add another `&` after the `)`.

Comment: @Jonathan  Your suggestion would probably make for more readable code, but sh -c cmd & has the same effect (modulo unimportant details) as ( sh -c cmd & ) &

Comment: Here are some final notes. I had to add a polling sleep loop to make sure that the pid file was generated. Any vars you want to use in the subshell command need to be exported, not just set.

Comment: Why would you add a polling sleep loop?  If you want to wait until the child is done, just call wait!

Comment: I don't need to wait until it is done I need to wait until it is started. Sometimes, pidfile was not created in time.

Comment: @Bob I've modified the solution so that the top level script does not exit until the pidfile exists, but does not involve a looping sleep.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks! I also hated the sleep but my bash-foo was not strong enough to get around it. This is way better.

Comment: Redirecting is not atomic. I feel it's possible a monitoring process would see an empty pidfile. Should it redirect to a temp file and then move it to pidfile since renames are atomic?

Comment: @user1011471 That is an excellent point.  Personally, I think that trying to do things robustly and correctly in a shell script like this is dangerous, and you're better off writing a proper daemon, but moving a tmpfile seems like a reasonable solution.  (Except that there is now a potential race condition with another process overwriting the tmpfile....which leads back to the first point)

Comment: @WilliamPursell You could use `mktemp` to create the tmpfile for some safety. I'm genuinely trying to learn (vs just arguing) so if that's not good enough, please do let me know. Also where can I read about what sets proper daemons apart from shell scripts?

Comment: Using `mktemp` wouldn't provide any additional safety.  If one process writes to a temp file, then another process checks and finds that the lock does not exist, then the first process copies the temp file over to the lock file, then the 2nd process does the same.  By a 'proper daemon', I just mean a process that invokes system calls directly, so there's fewer layers.  I didn't think you were being argumentative; apologies if it seemed like that.