# PID of the process that created the file

Tags: shell

Can I get the pid of `touch` when it's creating a file? I've tried `touch ID$! &` but it doesn't display the pid correctly. It takes the command before touch. Any advices?

Comment: How would that information be useful? The `touch` command will have completed before you're able to make any use of its PID.

Comment: I'd like to insert the PID of the touch that created the file in it's name. It's a part of an huge assignment.

Comment: Googling is your friend, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261397/bash-get-process-id-and-exit-code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write a small C or Perl program that calls `fork()` and then uses one of the `exec*()` functions to invoke `touch` from the child process. The parent process would receive the child's PID as the result of the `fork` call.

You say in a comment that you want to insert the PID into the name of the file. I can't think of a way to invoke `touch` with its own PID as part of its comand-line argument; you won't know the PID soon enough to do that. I suppose you could rename the file after `touch`ing it.

But the PID of the `touch` process isn't particularly meaningful. The process will have terminated before you can make any use of it.

If you just want a (more or less) unique number as part of the file name, I can't think of any good reason that it has to be the PID of the `touch` process. You could just do something like:

```
NEW_PID=$(sh -c 'echo $$')
touch foo-$NEW_PID.txt
```

which gives you the PID of a short-lived shell process.

Note that PIDs are not unique; since there are only finitely many possible PIDs, they're re-used after a while. (I've been able to force a PID to be reused in less than a minute by forking multiple processes very quickly.)

Answer (score 0):

This is touch rewritten in perl with the pid of the creating process as part of the filename

```
perl -e 'open(F,">".$$."myfile")||die $!'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need *that* pid, it's a multi-step process:

```
f=$(mktemp)
touch $f &
wait $!
mv $f ./ID$!
```